# Can I insert my code to my coded interface using Win32?

Tags: c, windows, user-interface, winapi

I have a C program and I am supposed to add an interface to it. Can I insert my code to my coded interface using Win32?

Example: Here is my code to convert binary into octal.

```c
void biTodec(){

    long long n;
    int dec = 0, i = 0, rem;
    printf("Enter a binary number: ");
    scanf("%lld", &n);
    while (n != 0) {
        rem = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        dec += rem * pow(2, i);
        ++i;
    }
    printf("%lld in binary = %d in decimal", n, dec);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I want my button in my API when clicked to perform the conversion. Here is my Win32 design

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM,LPARAM);

void AddMenus(HWND);
void AddControls(HWND);

HMENU hMenu;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow){

    WNDCLASSW kim = {0};
    kim.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;
    kim.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    kim.hInstance = hinst;
    kim.lpszClassName = L"myWindowClass";
    kim.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;

    if(!RegisterClassW(&kim))
        return -1;

    CreateWindowW(L"myWindowClass",L"Number System Converter", 
      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 500, 500, 
      NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    MSG msg={0};
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL,NULL, NULL)){
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
 
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp){

    switch(msg){

        case WM_COMMAND:
 
        switch(wp){
        case 1:
            MessageBoxA(hWnd, "This project was made by bla bla for 
        seven (7) days. He had no any prior idea on interface so he spent 
      the 6 out of 7 days just for researching. Copyright 2021", "About 
      the 
      project", NULL);

            break;
        case 2:
            MessageBeep(MB_OK);
            break;
        case 3:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case 4:
            MessageBeep(MB_OK);
            break;
        case 5:
            MessageBeep(MB_OK);
            break;
        }
    case WM_CREATE:
        AddMenus(hWnd);
        AddControls(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd,msg,wp,lp);

    }
}
void AddMenus(HWND hWnd){
    hMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hFileMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();

    AppendMenu(hSubMenu,MF_STRING, 4, "File");
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu,MF_STRING, 5, "Folder");
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, NULL, NULL);

    AppendMenu(hFileMenu,MF_POPUP,(UINT_PTR)hSubMenu, "Open");
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu,MF_STRING, 2, "Save");
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, NULL, NULL);
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu,MF_STRING, 3, "Exit");

    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP ,(UINT_PTR)hFileMenu, "Options");
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP ,1, "Help");


    SetMenu(hWnd, hMenu);
}

void AddControls(HWND hWnd){
    CreateWindowW(L"Static",L"Choose the number system to be converted", 
      WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,100, 30, 300, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL );

    CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"", WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER| WS_CHILD, 60, 80, 120, 30, hWnd, NULL, NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Generate", WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD, 
    200, 80, 80, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"", WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER| WS_CHILD, 300, 80, 
    120, 30, hWnd, NULL, NULL,NULL);

    CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Binary", 
      WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD|BS_RADIOBUTTON|WS_TABSTOP, 60, 150, 
      120, 20, hWnd,NULL , NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Decimal", 
     WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD|BS_RADIOBUTTON|WS_TABSTOP, 60, 180, 
     120, 20, hWnd,NULL , NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Octal", 
     WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD|BS_RADIOBUTTON|WS_TABSTOP, 60, 210, 
     120, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Hexadecimal", 
      WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD|BS_RADIOBUTTON|WS_TABSTOP,60, 240, 
     120, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

       CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Binary", 
      WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD|BS_RADIOBUTTON|WS_TABSTOP, 300, 150, 
      120, 20, hWnd,NULL , NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Decimal", 
      WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD|BS_RADIOBUTTON|WS_TABSTOP, 300, 180, 
      120, 20, hWnd,NULL , NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Octal", 
       WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD|BS_RADIOBUTTON|WS_TABSTOP, 300, 210, 
     120, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Hexadecimal", 
       WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD|BS_RADIOBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP, 300, 
      240, 120, 20, hWnd,NULL, NULL, NULL);

}
```

Is it possible to insert my code to the API or not? If not, can you suggest what I have to learn to create a user interface in my program?

Comment: Why not use the MSVC Dialog editor instead of your complex code?

Comment: @pau Because, you know, the dialog editor has been broken for close to a decade now. It's perfectly reasonable to not rely on technology that's notoriously frequently broken.

Comment: Did you try to compile your code? It contain errors and warnings. Please first fix that.

Comment: This is essentially the same as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68033638/1889329) and it ultimately boils down to: How do I write a Windows application while avoiding to learn how to write a Windows application? This isn't going to be useful.

Comment: Maybe you should first concentrate on writing a working basic Windows GUI program. If you have difficulties with that; then ask specific question. You can start with the code you show in your question. In the first step, just forget about your conversion routine and concentrate on removing all compilation errors and warnings.

Comment: The MSVC dialog editor works fine, as long as you are not trying to use the code-behind features. As a pure resource editor, it's OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your code and plugged your conversion function. I have not added more conversion - you'll do it yourself with my example - nor have I added enhancements.

To fix the Windows API part, note that I have:

Saved all HWND for the controls to be able to get/set values.

Used BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON and WS_GROUP so that radio button works as usual.

Used identifiers for all controls to be able to check which operation was requested.

Fixed various warnings using appropriate casts.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ID_CONV_SRC_BINARY       0x100
#define ID_CONV_SRC_OCTAL        0x101
#define ID_CONV_SRC_DECIMAL      0x102
#define ID_CONV_SRC_HEXADECIMAL  0x103
#define ID_CONV_DST_BINARY       0x200
#define ID_CONV_DST_OCTAL        0x201
#define ID_CONV_DST_DECIMAL      0x202
#define ID_CONV_DST_HEXADECIMAL  0x203
#define ID_GENERATE              0x300

int srcConvert = 0;
int dstConvert = 0;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

void AddMenus(HWND);
void AddControls(HWND);

HMENU hMenu;
HWND hNum, hOut;
HWND hWndInEdit;
HWND hWndOutEdit;
HWND hWndSrcBinary;
HWND hWndSrcOctal;
HWND hWndSrcDecimal;
HWND hWndSrcHexadecimal;
HWND hWndDstBinary;
HWND hWndDstOctal;
HWND hWndDstDecimal;
HWND hWndDstHexadecimal;

void biTodec(
    wchar_t * const inBuf,
    wchar_t * const outBuf,
    size_t outBufSize)
{
    long long n;
    int dec = 0, i = 0, rem;
    if (swscanf(inBuf, L"%lld", &n) == 1) {
        while (n != 0) {
            rem = n % 10;
            n /= 10;
            dec += rem * (1 << i);//pow(2, i);
            ++i;
        }
    }
    swprintf(outBuf, outBufSize, L"%d", dec);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hinst,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd) 
{
    WNDCLASSW kim = { 0 };
    kim.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;
    kim.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    kim.hInstance = hinst;
    kim.lpszClassName = L"myWindowClass";
    kim.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;

    if (!RegisterClassW(&kim))
        return -1;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(L"myWindowClass", L"Number System Converter", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        100, 100, 500, 500, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

void Generate(HWND hWnd)
{
    wchar_t inBuf[30];
    wchar_t outBuf[30];

    if (Button_GetCheck(hWndSrcBinary))
        srcConvert = ID_CONV_SRC_BINARY;
    else if (Button_GetCheck(hWndSrcDecimal))
        srcConvert = ID_CONV_SRC_DECIMAL;
    else if (Button_GetCheck(hWndSrcOctal))
        srcConvert = ID_CONV_SRC_OCTAL;
    else if (Button_GetCheck(hWndSrcHexadecimal))
        srcConvert = ID_CONV_SRC_HEXADECIMAL;
    else
        srcConvert = 0;

    if (Button_GetCheck(hWndDstBinary))
        dstConvert = ID_CONV_DST_BINARY;
    else if (Button_GetCheck(hWndDstDecimal))
        dstConvert = ID_CONV_DST_DECIMAL;
    else if (Button_GetCheck(hWndDstOctal))
        dstConvert = ID_CONV_DST_OCTAL;
    else if (Button_GetCheck(hWndDstHexadecimal))
        dstConvert = ID_CONV_DST_HEXADECIMAL;
    else
        dstConvert = 0;

    GetWindowText(hWndInEdit, inBuf, sizeof(inBuf) / sizeof(inBuf[0]));
    if ((srcConvert & 0xFF) == (dstConvert & 0xFF))
        wcscpy(outBuf, inBuf);
    else if ((srcConvert == ID_CONV_SRC_BINARY) && (dstConvert == ID_CONV_DST_DECIMAL))
        biTodec(inBuf, outBuf, sizeof(outBuf));
    else {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"Not implemented yet", L"Warning", MB_OK);
        outBuf[0] = 0;
    }
    SetWindowText(hWndOutEdit, outBuf);
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) 
{
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wp) {
        case ID_CONV_SRC_BINARY:
        case ID_CONV_SRC_DECIMAL:
        case ID_CONV_SRC_HEXADECIMAL:
        case ID_CONV_SRC_OCTAL:
        case ID_CONV_DST_BINARY:
        case ID_CONV_DST_DECIMAL:
        case ID_CONV_DST_HEXADECIMAL:
        case ID_CONV_DST_OCTAL:
        case ID_GENERATE:
            Generate(hWnd);
            break;
        case 1:
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"Copyright 2021", L"About the project", MB_OK);
            break;
        case 2:
            MessageBeep(MB_OK);
            break;
        case 3:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case 4:
            MessageBeep(MB_OK);
            break;
        case 5:
            MessageBeep(MB_OK);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        AddMenus(hWnd);
        AddControls(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
    return 0;
}

void AddMenus(HWND hWnd) {
    hMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hFileMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();

    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, 4, L"File");
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, 5, L"Folder");
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);

    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hSubMenu, L"Open");
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, 2, L"Save");
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, 3, L"Exit");

    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hFileMenu, L"Options");
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, 1, L"Help");

    SetMenu(hWnd, hMenu);
}

void AddControls(HWND hWnd) {
    CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Choose the number system to be converted",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 100,
        30, 300, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    hWndInEdit = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD, 60, 80, 120, 30, hWnd, NULL,
        NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Generate", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD, 200, 80, 80, 20, hWnd,
        (HMENU)ID_GENERATE,
        0, NULL);
    hWndOutEdit = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD, 300, 80, 120, 30, hWnd, NULL,
        NULL, NULL);

    hWndSrcBinary = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Binary", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP | WS_GROUP,
        60, 150, 120, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_CONV_SRC_BINARY, NULL, NULL);
    hWndSrcDecimal = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Decimal", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON, 
        60, 180, 120, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_CONV_SRC_DECIMAL, NULL, NULL);
    hWndSrcOctal = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Octal", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,  
        60, 210, 120, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_CONV_SRC_OCTAL, NULL, NULL);
    hWndSrcHexadecimal = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Hexadecimal", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON, 
        60, 240, 120, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_CONV_SRC_HEXADECIMAL, NULL, NULL);

    hWndDstBinary = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Binary", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP | WS_GROUP,
        300, 150, 120, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_CONV_DST_BINARY, NULL, NULL);
    hWndDstDecimal = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Decimal", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON, ,
        300, 180, 120, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_CONV_DST_DECIMAL, NULL, NULL);
    hWndDstOctal = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Octal", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON, 
        300, 210, 120, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_CONV_DST_OCTAL, NULL, NULL);
    hWndDstHexadecimal = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Hexadecimal", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON, 
        300, 240, 120, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_CONV_DST_HEXADECIMAL, NULL, NULL);

}
```

There are plenty room for enhancements. I made the minimum to answer your question. Open more questions if you need more help.

Comment: Hi Sir @fpiette, whatever binary number i enter, the conversion to decimal is zero. what should I fix sir?

Comment: @kim2002 Debug your `biTodec` function to see what goes wrong.